# Can't open an existing file in Sdcard in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, record

I have this code in my project to read an audio file :

**MainActivity2:**

```
private String getFilename() { 
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
}

private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
    Log.i("Tag", getFilename());
    ListeAudio.put(indice,getFilename()); // here is ListeAudio
    path=getFilename();
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
File AudioFile = new File( MainActivity2Activity.ListeAudio.get(z));
    // ListeAudio return /storage/sdcard0/AudioRecorder/1433288052123.mp4    
    Uri AudioUri = Uri.fromFile(AudioFile);
    vocal = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,AudioUri);
    vocal.start();
```

that's doesn't work and in logcat there is an error who say:
Failed to open file '/storage/sdcard0/AudioRecorder/1433288052123.mp4'. (No such file or directory)
And when i search manually this path in the file explorer i found the audio
file wich i want to play.
I have this in the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the implementation of your call `MainActivity2Activity.ListeAudio.get(z)`? Try to use the system api to access the external storage.

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    File audioFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsoluteFile()
                + File.separator
                + "AudioRecorder/1433288052123.mp4");
    if (audioFile.exists()) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(audioFile));
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

**// EDIT**

```
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
    Log.i("Tag", getFilename());
    ListeAudio.put(indice,getFilename()); // here is ListeAudio
```

The file path your write to and the file path your save are not the same file, `getFilename()` will return a unique file path every time it get called.

Change to this, if you want to use current milliseconds as the file name.

```
    final String filePath = getFilename();
    recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
    Log.i("Tag", filePath);
    ListeAudio.put(indice, filePath); // here is ListeAudio
```

Comment: when i record audio i save the file and i add the path in ListeAudio to use it in another activity

Comment: @Omar then you have to make sure the recorded file is readable.

Comment: @Omar what does it say when call `audioFile.exists()`?

Comment: The path wich i guive to the AudioFile Constructor is saved when i save the record so there is a method startRecording in this method i add the path in the ListeAudio

Comment: There is a problem in you `getFileName`, it returns the current milliseconds as the file name very time it called. Check my edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getExternalFilesDir()` instead of hard-coding your filepath.

```
File AudioFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir() + "/" + "yourFile.ext")
```

Comment: i have to read audio from the path in MainActivity2.ListeAudio